# is "$(\psi_u^*\psi_d + \psi_d^*\psi_u)$" the mathematical manifestation of interference?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference

Suppose that we have the following quantum superposition state:

$$(\psi_u+\psi_d)/\sqrt{2}$$

u=up and d=down represent the orthonormal basis of a space state associated with a spin

And the probability density is:

$$[|\psi_u|^2 + |\psi_d|^2 + (\psi_u^*\psi_d + \psi_d^*\psi_u)]/2$$

Does the term "$(\psi_u^*\psi_d + \psi_d^*\psi_u)$" represent the mathematical manifestation of interference?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Do you want to know why is that term called interference? It's because it resembles the interference term between two electric fields in optics.

Comment: I want to grasp the connection between the mathematical expressions and the physical meaning. thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is probably only the real part of that state's interference and there are other states with interesting interference patterns where that term is zero but $\psi_u^* \psi_d - \psi_d^* \psi_u$ is nonzero. There is a systematic ambiguity with what you're writing, but let me write $|\psi\rangle = \alpha |\uparrow\rangle + \beta |\downarrow\rangle$ to make this a little more clear (you might mean either $\alpha$ or $|\uparrow\rangle$ by $\psi_u$).

It might be better to look holistically at this state's density matrix, $$\rho=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\alpha^*&\beta^*\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}|\alpha|^2 & \alpha~\beta^*\\\beta~\alpha^*&|\beta|^2\end{bmatrix}.$$
The off-diagonal elements generally are said to encode the interference pattern; however, remember please that this is basis-sensitive as $\rho$ is Hermitian and can be diagonalized in some basis, and its eigenspaces will then be orthogonal.

What's really happening is that your $|\uparrow\rangle$ state is being evolved to some amplitude $\phi_\uparrow(x, y)$ for a photon to hit a 2D screen, and your $|\downarrow\rangle$ state is being evolved to some $\phi_\downarrow(x, y)$  amplitude; the distribution you see is then $$|\alpha \phi_\uparrow + \beta \phi_\downarrow|^2 = |\alpha\phi_\uparrow|^2 + |\beta\phi_\downarrow|^2 + 2 \operatorname{Re}\big(\alpha\beta^*\phi_\uparrow\phi_\downarrow^*\big),$$and the rightmost term creates the wavy interference fringes seen in the spaces where $\phi_\uparrow$ and $\phi_\downarrow$ overlap.

Comment: Thank you! I prefer your notation also... I will think about it and ask if necessary.

Comment: whats 2 Re?
and, its the same if I write?:
$$
|\alpha \phi_\uparrow + \beta \phi_\downarrow|^2 = |\alpha\phi_\uparrow|^2 + |\beta\phi_\downarrow|^2 +(\alpha\phi_\uparrow^*\beta\phi_\downarrow + \beta\phi_\downarrow^*\alpha\phi_\uparrow)/2
$$

Comment: Don't divide by 2 in your expression, and pay attention to the phases of the complex numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$. $\operatorname{Re} z = (z + z^*)/2$ is function which takes the real part of a complex number; that is if $z = x + i y$ then $\operatorname{Re}z = x.$ If you prefer, $|z|^2 = z~z^*$ so $|u + v|^2 = u~u^* + u~v^* + v~u^* + v~v^*,$ work out the formula from that.

Comment: Could you extend a little more on the phases of α and β please?

Comment: Each one is a complex number $\alpha = re^{i\phi},\beta = se^{i\chi}.$ The angles $\phi, \chi$ are known as their complex phases. Complex conjugates  have the opposite phase as $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$ and reversing the sign of $\theta$ yields the complex conjugate $e^{-i\theta} = \cos\theta - i \sin\theta.$ The real part of $\alpha~\beta^*\phi_\uparrow~\phi_\downarrow^*$ is going to depend on what this overall phase is, which by the exponent-adding rules, is just the sum of the phases of $\alpha$ and $\phi_\uparrow$ minus the sum of the phases of $\beta$ and $\phi_\downarrow.$